# Should I use a sharepoint 2010 publishing portal for our intranet redesign?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, portal, intranet, web-publishing

I am building out a redesign of our corporate intranet on sharepoint 2010. We have three web applications: My sites, Team or Organization sites, and the Intranet “portal”.

On the intranet I want to read lists from Team sites of type announcements and calendar and aggregate them together. Then, on the Intranet, I’d like to have some editorial control as to what actually shows up. By default, I’d like list items to show up on the intranet, but would also like to be able to hide or delete them if deemed not important enough.

Would I benefit from using a publishing portal for the Intranet?

Would it make sense to write a web part to read the lists, sync the lists into a new list on the intranet, and then the content manager could uncheck the ‘display’ check box?

What is the best way to implement this type of infrastructure?

Where’s the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you're wanting to syndicate lists from you Team/Organisation sites.

For this you could use a Data View Web Part connected to the lists.asmx webservice of the teams/orgs web app for a middle tier approach. You could include a field on your content types in the teams/orgs web app to indicate if a record should show on the intrnet and include that in your query when retrieving items.

As to using Publishing..... Will you have traditional web pages in your intranet? if so, then yes, use it, if not then I can't see a huge benefit.